# Convert control to html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I need to "translate" devexpress control (for example check box) to html string in the controller. Like it looks on page. Please advise how to do it.

Page:

```
<input name="myCheckBox" id="chB_S" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; position: relative; background-color: transparent;" readonly="readonly" value="I"/>
```

Controller:

```
CheckBoxSettings s = new CheckBoxSettings();
s.Name = "myCheckBox";
s.Properties.ClientSideEvents.ValueChanged = "function(s,e){alert('Selection changed');}";
CheckBoxExtension chBut = new CheckBoxExtension(s);        
string zzz = chBut.GetHtml().ToHtmlString(); //Get empty string instead of html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string RenderView(string path, object data)
{
    Page pageHolder = new Page();
    UserControl viewControl = (UserControl) pageHolder.LoadControl(path);

    if (data != null)
    {
        Type viewControlType = viewControl.GetType();            
        FieldInfo field = viewControlType.GetField("Data");

        if (field != null)
        {
            field.SetValue(viewControl, data);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("View file: " + path + " does not have a public Data property");
        }
    }

    pageHolder.Controls.Add(viewControl);

    StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);

    return output.ToString();
}
```

The above method can be used with ASP.NET application to convert UserControl to HTML. You can refer it as a guide to create a custom RenderView to convert the Controls to Html.

Moreover (not sure about MVC) but in asp.net all controls are derived from WebControls so I think you can also do the same. Working with MVC controls now will update in case succeeded.